# How can we check if the current OS is win8 or blue

Tags: c#, windows-8, environment-variables, development-environment, windows-8.1

Win8.1 and Win8 has the same OS Version. How can we check if the current OS is Win8 or Blue? 
The Environment.OSVersion is giving us the same results:

`Environment.OSVersion                           6.2.9200.0
    Environment.OSVersion.Version                   6.2.9200.0
    Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major             6
    Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor             2`

Comment: It is a preRelease. Things like OSVersion can change...

Comment: Check `Environment.OSVersion.Version.Revision`. It *should* be 9200 for Win8, and 9431 for the Win8.1 Preview.

Comment: thats strange! my win8.1 Pro Preview

Comment: and it shows the OSVersion as 9200

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What do you hope to achieve here?

Comment: @Tim Heuer: Sometimes it's handy for analytics purposes; e.g., buy getting the *actual* OS version used across a product line you can start to make decision about what versions to support going forward.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Windows 8.1 will [lie to you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and tell you it is Window 8.  Changing that lie requires editing the manifest that is embedded in your program so that Windows knows you don't want to be lied to.  Project + Add New Item, select the Application Manifest File item template.  Copy paste this verbiage underneath the `<application>` element:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
    </application> 
</compatibility>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution  under this Registry Key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to get Hans' solution working, I created a different solution:

```
bool _IsWindows8Point1OrGreater = Type.GetType("Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout, Windows.UI.Xaml, ContentType=WindowsRuntime", false) != null;
```

Comment: Just tested on win8 and 8.1 as well, both return false.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting after 7 months. I just tested on Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, both return true. Now what? The "Runtime" part might be worth noting: The solution is for RT.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Win8.1 the version is 6.3.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are using GetVersionEx() api [from kernel32.dll] for getting Win8.1 version, the value returned will be 6.2.* whereas the version value should be 6.3.*

The solution to this is either you need to add assembly manifest to 
the .net exe or os.dll to state that symhelp will run on windows 8.1, 
that might make the .net System.Environment.OSVersion.Version function correctly.

However you need to test it on multiple OS's.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx