# Wix setup - check if windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, version

Need to check if msi is running on Windows Server 2012 with R2. So, if it runs on Server 2012 - error. If it runs on windows 8 - OK. If it runs on any Server 2008 - OK.

I tried the following condition, but it shows error also on win 8, why?

```
<Condition Message='This application only runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 or higher'>
  NOT VersionNT = 602 AND MsiNTProductType > 1
</Condition>
```

Comment: The same problem:<Condition Message='This application only runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 or higher'>
         <![CDATA[(NOT VersionNT = 602 AND NOT MsiNTProductType > 1)]]>      
    </Condition>

Comment: FOUND!                  <![CDATA[NOT (VersionNT = 602 AND MsiNTProductType = 3)]]>

Answer (score 3):

As you discovered, you're interested in the [VersionNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MsiNTProductType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properties.

However, launch conditions use a positive syntax -- you specify the **valid** condition(s). The `NOT` in your comment's answer will cause the installer to fail for Windows Server 2012 and proceed for everything else.

Also note that Windows Server 2012 R2's version is 6.03, not 6.02.

For Windows Server 2012 R2 only, you want:

```
<Condition Message="This application only runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 or higher">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT>=603 AND MsiNTProductType=3]]>
</Condition>
```

I used `VersionNT>=603` to reflect that your error string says "...or higher."

For Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8:

```
<Condition Message="This application only runs on...">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT>=602]]>
</Condition>
```

For Windows Server 2012, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2008:

```
<Condition Message="This application only runs on...">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT>=602 OR (VersionNT>=600 AND MsiNTProductType=3)]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Please also see this SO post about obtaining the correct `VersionNT` property for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 when using a bootstrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055285/how-do-i-get-msi-to-return-the-correct-versionnt-value-when-running-on-windows-2

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to validate the WS2012 R2, if still help somebody:

```
    <![CDATA[(VersionNT64 = 603 AND MsiNTProductType <> 1)]]>
```