# IN guest account in windows 8 how to determine the version of windows?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

When we log in from guest account in Windows 8 and try to find the version it give error and the same value as Windows 8. Please suggest some code OR API which will work for both windows 8 and Windows 8.1

Comment: You should ask this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko He wants to do this with code.

Comment: @OP What are you using currently to get the version?

Comment: *When we log in from guest account in Windows 8 and try to find the version it give ... same value as Windows 8* Yeah, Windows 8 will report that it's Windows 8...

Answer (score 0):

This gives you some background knowledge: 
[How can we check if the current OS is win8 or blue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406850/how-can-we-check-if-the-current-os-is-win8-or-blue/)

And this is what works for me:

```
// this might only work as long as there's no successor to Windows 8.1
public Version GetVersion()
{
   var reportedVersion = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version;
   if (reportedVersion.Major==6 && reportedVersion.Minor==2)
   {
      bool _IsWindows8Point1OrGreater = Type.GetType("Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout, Windows.UI.Xaml, ContentType=WindowsRuntime", false) != null;
      if(_IsWindows8Point1OrGreater )
      reportedVersion = new Version(6,3); 
   }
   return reportedVersion;
}
```

Comment: it will gives the result in true and false. I want the code which works for both windows 8 and 8.1 correctly.

Comment: So, how many different version do you expect when you tag your question with "Windows 8"??? ... I amended above post.

Comment: You should consider why you need to know whether it's *exactly* 8.0 or 8.1 rather than *at least* 8.0 or 8.1.

Comment: ta.speot.is: a good reason is that some apis behave differently when running on 8.1; even if the app is compiled for 8.0.

Comment: But if that behaviour is here to stay, then checking for 8.1 is silly because when 8.2 comes your code will fail. That's why you check *at least* 8.1

Comment: Correct. Hence the comment above the code. If that behaviour is here to stay we'll have to add the next workaround as soon as 8.2 or 9.0 is released. ;-)