# Will GetVersionEx lie about service packs as well?

Tags: winapi, versioning, windows-8.1

Starting with Windows 8.1, [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) no longer returns the "true" version number, but [might return a lower value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There a no service packs for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 yet, but when they are available, will GetVersionEx lie about them (`wServicePackMajor` and `wServicePackMinor` in [OSVERSIONINFOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) as well?

Comment: The change was made _"due to undesirable customer behaviors resulting from how the GetVersion(Ex) APIs have been used in the past"_. Due to you asking this question, I guess you're one of the targeted customers. Use feature detection, not version detection. If you can explain _why_ you need the version number, how you are using it and what specifically you are afraid of breaking when the version number does or does not change when a service pack has been installed, might help getting accurate answers that address your original problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Objection noted, and I do understand the intention behind this. Still, there are cases where determining the actual version number or service pack level is desirable (think about diagnostics tools, for example), so I still think that the question does have value.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Since you are curious (although this is unrelated to the technical content of the question): In our case, we contractually guarantee that a certain version of our software will work with certain versions and service pack levels of Windows. As a service to the user, we show a small, nonintrusive message if these conditions are not met. As you can see, the "original problem" is a business/legal requirement, not a technical one. I am not seeking advice on the business/legal requirement here.

Comment: It seems to me the answer is right on the second page you linked. See the info about manifesting 8.1 (and how it won't affect running on previous versions) but will solve your `GetVersionEx()` concern. There's also `VERSIONHELPERAPI` (same page), which adds things like `IsWindows7SP1OrGreater()`, `IsWindows8OrGreater()` and ' IsWindows8_1OrGreater()`; one would presume that when Windows 8.1 SP1 is released, they'll add the corresponding `IsWindows81SP1OrGreater()` to the list, I'd think.

Comment: Have you considered using `VerifyVersionInfo`, which is more sincere? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119582/2604492

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft forever does battle with well-intended code that a programmer writes to check the Windows version.  Which was typically written to deal with *older* Windows versions.  But forgets to do something reasonable with a *newer* Windows version.

So they spend massive amounts of effort on targeted compatibility shims that intentionally lie about the Windows version when a specific program asks for it.  A never-ending battle whenever they release a new Windows version.  Certainly a losing battle, the number of programs they need to test is staggering.

So at Windows 8.1 they said "no more", deprecated GetVersionEx() and intentionally lie out of the box, returning version 8.0.  You need to add [an entry to the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409126/17034) to turn off the lie.  Which *probably* will turn off a lie about the service pack as well.  Or might require an updated GUID, fairly unlikely.  We of course can't be sure until that happens.